# How can we Save modified PDF file from mozilla pdf.js to our personal server(cross Domain) with out downloding the file?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf.js

Here is something I have tried. When we browse the bloburl, it has the pdf data with all modifications.
when I try to upload the blob file to server the file is corrupted. I can't open it in pdf viewer. when I try to open the saved file in server using chrome, it opens and only the modified data is showing. All other content are corrupted.

**Please suggest any method you see fit.**

```js
var blobUrl = "blob:http://localhost/6e28b1f8-65c2-4457-a8f6-bffaab5f2347";
const data = await fetch(blobUrl);            
const blob = await data.blob();       

var formData = new FormData();   
formData.append("file", blob,"filename.pdf");

await fetch('http://localhost:54402//Controller//Methode', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
.then(response => response)
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

C#

```
public ActionResult Methode(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I have to ask: what is with the blobUrl stuff? Why is this necessary?

Comment: Since you've only provided the JS code, can we assume that you've tracked the issue to this point? If so, the C# tag doesn't belong on your question. If you haven't, then you should show us the C# code.

Comment: when i"am trying to crack the download method. i got that stuff. we can download the file using the blobUrl. blob is somthing like DOM it has the pdf data stored in our browser. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: I understand the concept of blob, but I don't understand its use in your question as a means for obtaining PDF data. Even the [pdfjs docs](https://pdfjs.express/documentation/basic-operations/save-document/blob) show a much more direct way to get the document as a blob.

Comment: https://pdfjs.express/documentation/basic-operations/save-document/blob
it is a paid version (pdfjs.express)
im using the open source version
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: I see. Well, my suggestion for resolving this issue is to first determine where the issue lies. We haven't seen how you're saving it on the C# side, so perhaps you're doing something funky there. Or perhaps it's not being sent from the Javascript side correctly. Please provide more information, and ideally a [mcve].

Comment: in C# side just i'am doing is copy the file to a sever directry.
The copy process is safe and there is no problem.
becouse im using the the logic for a while,for uploading file to server